# I/O issue with AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Currently we have a number of Amazon AWS c3.large setups and I'm trying to figure out the bottle neck. The load is very high on most of them during our peak periods.

It looks to be high disk utilization as iostat is at 100 for the majority of the time with respect to %util (last column):

```
iostat -x 1 Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util xvdap1            0.00 
0.00    0.00   68.00     0.00 16712.00   245.76   137.40 1924.29  14.71 100.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.51    0.00    6.06   93.43    0.00    0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util xvdap1            0.00    
0.00    0.00   69.00     0.00 16560.00   240.00   136.34 1895.94  14.49 100.00
```

The thought might be that the IOPS used with the 64 GB General Purpose SSD might not be enough (192 IOPS).

Although watching the tps (IOPS) seems to average about 70-80. So it seems to be enough. But I do notice some occasional high bursts well above that. I believe that shouldn't be a problem either as the bursts are up to 3000.

```
sar -b 1
Linux 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64 (ip-10-167-69-88)      03/04/2016      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

09:08:35 PM       tps      rtps      wtps   bread/s   bwrtn/s
09:08:36 PM     78.12      1.04     77.08      8.33  16700.00
09:08:37 PM     73.74      0.00     73.74      0.00  16880.81
09:08:38 PM     76.77      1.01     75.76      8.08  16452.53
09:08:39 PM     68.69      0.00     68.69      0.00  16678.79
09:08:40 PM     72.92      0.00     72.92      0.00  17250.00
09:08:41 PM     72.04      0.00     72.04      0.00  17677.42
09:08:42 PM    144.68      0.00    144.68      0.00   9480.85
09:08:43 PM    141.05      0.00    141.05      0.00   9574.74
09:08:44 PM     97.98      0.00     97.98      0.00  13664.65
09:08:45 PM    185.26      0.00    185.26      0.00   4244.21
09:08:46 PM     96.91      0.00     96.91      0.00  14564.95
09:08:47 PM     68.32      0.00     68.32      0.00  16324.75
09:08:48 PM     66.67      0.00     66.67      0.00  16703.03
```

Do you think the problem is the number of IOPS allocated or should I be looking at something else?

Comment: Run `top` and watch the `wa` CPU percentage in the header. That's the amount of time the system is spending waiting on IO to complete.

Comment: tps == iops I suspect only for operations <= 256KiB.  A 1MiB op is 4 IOPS.

Comment: @EEAA %wa is always high ~80-90% but it fluctuates a lot.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so the fact that I have 192 IOPS is actually divided by 4 for any >1MiB operation?

Comment: 1 IOPS is consumed by each disk transaction of 256KiB or less; larger chunks consume multiples, so a single trx of 1.25MiB consumes 5, 2MiB consumes 8, etc.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html

Comment: Of course you needn't guess -- there are cloudwatch metrics on the EBS volume to show you what EBS thinks you are consuming.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's the strange thing: `Consumed Read Write Ops` is a graph for all volumes but it never graphs anything? All other graphs have values except this one and one other.

Comment: Sorry, I used the word "consuming" in a generic sense above... the graphs labeled "consumed" are only populated on provisioned IOPS volumes. You're looking for the read and write operations counters, which you'll need to divide by the metric interval to get ops/sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IO subsystem (aka disks) are your problem here. Your system is spending a *huge* amount of time waiting for IO requests to be fulfilled. I tend to start looking at upgrades whenever my systems reach ~5% iowait. Needless to say, you're way beyond that.

You'll need to increase the amount of IOPS that are available to your system. Your first option is migrate to a PIOPS (Provisioned IOPS) EBS volume if you're not already using one. After doing that, then increase the IOPS setting until you get the performance you need.

Comment: So why is the cloud so good again?

Comment: @eewhite cloud is good because it gives you options. People with low requirements pay a little, people with high requirements pay more. In some cases it's cheaper or easier than owning hardware.

Comment: @ewwhite this is an SSD hard drive with a managed, mirrored, redundant mate that OP is only paying something like $6.40/month for, depending in the AWS region.  The performance seems *beyond* reasonable for the price.